# how to parse local HTML table using R

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing

I have a local "html" file ("117E.html") which contains a table (of some biological data) and I want to parse this table in R and read all it's columns and rows into an R data frame, the file is available only locally so I don't have a url address instead I want to parse the local one:

I tried the following command for parsing using the "XML" package in R, however, the resultant "tables" we empty

```
tables=readHTMLTable(doc="117E.html",header=T,as.data.frame=T)
```

the following is the html file, so if you want to see how my html file looks like copy this following part and paste it in a separate .html file name it 117E.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<title>Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
</p><table border="1" /><tr><th>Seq_ID</th><th>Match_region</th>  <th>Superfamily E_value</th><th>SCOP superfamily</th><th>Family E_value</th> <th>SCOP family</th><th>Closest structure</th><th>Alignment</th></tr><tr> <th>117E:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE</th><th>2-282</th><th>1.15e-110</th><th><a     href="http://supfam.org/SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin/scop.cgi?sunid=50324">Inorganic  pyrophosphatase</a></th><th>3.60e-11</th><th><a href="http://supfam.org /SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin/scop.cgi?sunid=50325">Inorganic pyrophosphatase</a> </th><th><a href="http://supfam.org/SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin /scop.cgi?sunid=25395">8prk A:</a></th><th> <pre>YTTRQIGAKNTLEYKVYIEKDGKPVSAFHDIPLYADKENNIFNMVVEIPR<br>WTNAKLEITKEETLNPIIQDTKKGKLRFVRNCFPHHGYIHNYGAFPQTWE<br>DPNVSHPETKAVGDNEPIDVLEIGETIAYTGQVKQVKALGIMALLDEGET<br>DWKVIAIDINDPLAPKLNDIEDVEKYFPGLLRATNEWFRIYKIPDGKPEN<br>QFAFSGEAKNKKYALDIIKETHDSWKQLIAGKSSDSKGIDLTNVTLPDTP<br>TYSKAASDAIPPASLKADAPIDKSIDKWFFI<br></pre> </th></tr><tr><th>117E:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE</th><th>2-282</th><th>1.15e-110</th><th><a href="http://supfam.org/SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin/scop.cgi?sunid=50324">Inorganic pyrophosphatase</a></th><th>3.60e-11</th><th><a href="http://supfam.org/SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin/scop.cgi?sunid=50325">Inorganic pyrophosphatase</a></th><th><a href="http://supfam.org/SUPERFAMILY/cgi-bin/scop.cgi?sunid=25395">8prk A:</a></th><th><pre>YTTRQIGAKNTLEYKVYIEKDGKPVSAFHDIPLYADKENNIFNMVVEIPR<br>WTNAKLEITKEETLNPIIQDTKKGKLRFVRNCFPHHGYIHNYGAFPQTWE<br>DPNVSHPETKAVGDNEPIDVLEIGETIAYTGQVKQVKALGIMALLDEGET<br>DWKVIAIDINDPLAPKLNDIEDVEKYFPGLLRATNEWFRIYKIPDGKPEN<br>QFAFSGEAKNKKYALDIIKETHDSWKQLIAGKSSDSKGIDLTNVTLPDTP<br>TYSKAASDAIPPASLKADAPIDKSIDKWFFI<br></pre></th></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the [XML package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2195555/alko989 I tried but the resultant is empty variable: this is the command I used     tables=readHTMLTable(doc="117E.html",header=T,as.data.frame=T)

Comment: Your opening table tag is incorrect. It should be `<table border="1">`, not `<table border="1" />`. Works just fine if you correct that. (You also have a closing paragraph tag `</p>` without having ever opened with `<p>`, but this doesn't prevent readHTMLTable from working once you fix your table tag